# Is there a (Linux) C++ IDE that can 'construct' a project from a makefile?

Tags: c++, linux

I am working on a legacy C app which uses makefiles. I am more comfortable (and more productive) working from within an IDE, so I am looking for an IDE that can import the makefile and create a project.

Incidentally, these are hand written makefiles (not complicated ones like those generated by Autoconf). I am using Code::Blocks at the moment, but it seems it is unable to import makefiles ...

Comment: By the way, what are some highlights for Code::Blocks you personally found fond of? I never really got into it, but recently I've heard some positive comments.

Comment: Eclipse can run whatever build command you want, you just write the 'eclipse make' targets you need. I run make, cmake, doxygen and others from there

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 3):

The last time I checked, [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) can [import makefile projects](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_import.htm&cp=8_1_3) or [generate](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=426348) makefiles for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think that most do. For a fact QTCreator and Eclipse can deal with makefile based projects appropriatedly.

In eclipse CDT (last one I have used) just create a C++ project specifying the current location of your project and tell it to use an empty makefile. That will create an Eclipse project that uses the existing makefile (untouched)

Comment: As an update, QtCreator can no longer handle makefile projects.

Comment: @Dzarda where did you get this update ? Last I checked it still does !!

Comment: @RishavAmbasta Let me rephrase, it can not _create_ Makefile projects.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you make some hard assumptions on what can and cannot happen in the make file, I doubt what you describe is even theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1):

The autotools chain is quite a patchwork system -- there isn't enough structure in the toolchain for an IDE to "import" the project consitantly and correctly. However, some IDE's (e.g., eclipse and netbeans) can import them, provided the build script **follow** certain popular conventions.

If you want to work with code in the most robust manner (cross platform, cross IDE etc) I would find a set of tools that are designed to be portable.

So, what I am driving at is that you need a robust build system. A robust build system would compile the same code base on any OS/IDE. In order to achieve this you need to be able to specify your build needs at yet a higher level of abstraction. Tools exist to do this, and in the C/C++ world [CMAKE](http://www.cmake.org/) is the popular choice. Once you have written a CMAKE description of your project you can target any IDE.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about CMAKE. I think I will use CMAKE. However, I need to be able to be able to navigate from an error to the file in which the error occured (for compilation errors) - and for that I will need an IDE ... am I missing something?

Comment: Well if you get cmake to generate IDE projects then the IDE can parse the strings. Emacs and Vim can parse error strings. I personally use a bash window and read the error strings myself :D

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is buildint  makefile base projects. if you do it that way however YOU are  responsible to keep this makefile up to date. And this  can  makefile is the usually way it is done in Linux IDES, the IDES generate the  Makefile  but  the otherway generating Projects from Makefile is not supporte.

Comment: best ? how do you quantify that. There are better ways these days.

Comment: best to integrate  makefiles of course there may be better ways. But the OP wants to have a project generated from a Makefile and AFAIKT this option is not offered anywhere.